# Use Javascript onclick or keydown for event

Tags: javascript, onclick, keydown

I'm using JavaScript and CSS to create keys that flips and play a sound. On the front side there is an image then when the key is pressed, it plays a sound and flips to revels the back which displays a different img and flips back over after the key is released. The code works for that purpose, but I want the same functionality for when someone also clicks the key. Can I have both?

```
function removeTransition(e) {
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
  }

  function playSound(e) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio) return;

    key.classList.add('playing');
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
  }

  const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
  keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
  window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have both, you can do something like this:

```
function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
  e.target.classList.remove('playing');
}

function playSound(e) {
  let keyCode;
  if (e.type === 'click') {
    keyCode = e.currentTarget.dataset.key;
  } else {
    keyCode = e.keyCode;
  }

  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return;

  key.classList.add('playing');
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
}

const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('click', playSound))
```

I've used [event.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type) to determine if the event is a `click` or a `keydown` and used [element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to retrieve the appropriate key in case of `click` events (these events don't have the `keyCode` property).

Also, in case of `click` events, `event.target` is actually the clicked key, you can use that instead of looking for the key in the DOM (the `` querySelector(`div[data-key="${keyCode}"]`) `` call).

Comment: When trying this, the keydown still works, but not the click.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dustin Do `div`s that have the `data-key` attribute also have the `key` class ? That was my assumption.

Comment: The data-key is setup like below

`
<audio data-key="81" src="my-sound.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="87" src="my-sound.mp3"></audio>
  <audio data-key="69" src="my-sound.mp3"></audio> 
`
The  .key is setup like this 
```
<div data-key="81" class=" key">
            
            <div class="sides front-key">
                <img src="img.jpg"
                <p><kbd>Q</kbd></p>
            </div>
            <div class="sides back-key">
                <img src="img.jpg"
                <p><kbd>Q</kbd></p>
            </div>
        </div>
````

Comment: Thanks for the update and sorry for my messy comment. However, I'm still having the same issue. The keydown works, but not clicking

Comment: @dustin Check the console, see if there are any errors, also, check if `playSound` is called when you click a button and if `e.currentTarget` is the clicked button.

Comment: I see this error:
TypeError: key.addEvenListener is not a functionindex.html:377:25

Comment: @dustin Oh, is a function name misspell, it should be `addEventListener` instead of `addEvenListener`.

Comment: Ah... That did it! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @dustin I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as I am concerned, you can have as many event listeners per object as you want. Just use the relevant event listeners and attach them to the relevant HTML objects. Remember, in Javascript you need an event listener for each event.
For example: (from https://gomakethings.com/listening-to-multiple-events-in-vanilla-js/)

This doesn't work:

```
document.addEventListener('click mouseover', function (event) {
    // this doesn't work
}, false);
```

Instead, you'll have to do something like this:

```
var someFunction = function (event) {
    // Do something...
};

// Add our event listeners
window.addEventListener('click', someFunction, false);
window.addEventListener('mouseover', someFunction, false);
```